# Print all POST request parameters without knowing their names

Tags: python, web-services, post, flask, request

**How can I print all parameters that were passed in with a POST request using Python and flask?**

I know how to ask for a parameter by name

```
from flask import  request
key = request.args.get('key')
```

But i'm not sure why this did not work for me:

```
for a in request.args:
        print "argument: " + a
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`request.args` returns a `MultiDict`. It can have multiple values for each key. In order to print all parameters, you can try:

The code below works for URLs with parameters added,like:

```
 http://www.webservice.my/rest?extraKey=extraValue
    multi_dict = request.args
    for key in multi_dict:
        print multi_dict.get(key)
        print multi_dict.getlist(key)
```

For parameters embedded within the POST request as a form:

```
dict = request.form
for key in dict:
    print 'form key '+dict[key]
```

See the example [here](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict) and you will have a good idea.

Comment: if you are posting the values through html form.This would help to you `print request.form`